# Show multiline plain text of textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, line-breaks

I just want to show multiline plain text of textarea but I don't want to show the textarea.

Example:

Textarea:

```
|===================|
| First line        |
| Second line       |
|___________________|
```

Multiline plain text:

```
First line
Second line
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you want to do? replace the `'\r\n'` by `<br />` or hide the area's borders?

Comment: As I understood, you can use this style for your textarea: `border:none; background:transparent;`

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/82cTq/ ?

Comment: @StrubT: I want to hide border and disable editable of textarea.

Comment: @Bood Carley: As far as I can see, you already found your answer.

Comment: @StrubT: Yes, friend. I choose use <pre> tag. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp), which defines preformatted text and preserves both spaces and line breaks:

```
var txt="First line\nSecond line";
document.body.innerHTML+="<pre>"+txt+"</pre>";
```

Or if you want to do it with CSS or you want more options about whitespaces and linebreaks, you can use CSS property [`white-space`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

Javascript:

```
var txt="First line\nSecond line";
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=txt;
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv{white-space:pre;}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS for textarea:

```
textarea { 
    border-style: none; 
    border-color: Transparent; 
    overflow: auto;        
  }
```